# is this code breaking mvvm architecture in any way? if yes, how? And what can be done instead?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

**is there anything wrong with this specific line of code in terms of mvvm pattern?**

```
viewModel.selectEnvironment(selectedBuildType, viewModel.getIsIgnoreCaptchaEnabled());
```

**Code for reference -**

*Activity*

```
viewModel.selectEnvironment(selectedBuildType, viewModel.getIsIgnoreCaptchaEnabled());

binding.switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            viewModel.setIgnoreCaptchaEnabled(isChecked);
            viewModel.enableCaptcha();
});
```

*Viewmodel*

```
 public void selectEnvironment(@NonNull final String environmentName, boolean isChecked) {
buildTypeManager.setBuildType(effectiveEnvironment);
            enableCaptcha();
        }

public void enableCaptcha() {
            if (isIgnoreCaptchaEnabled) {
                // some logic
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }
    
    public boolean getIsIgnoreCaptchaEnabled() {
            return isIgnoreCaptchaEnabled;
        }
    
     public void setIgnoreCaptchaEnabled(boolean isIgnoreCaptchaEnabled) {
            this.isIgnoreCaptchaEnabled = isIgnoreCaptchaEnabled;
        }
```